# Null pointer exception when reading images from database second time

Tags: android, database, nullpointerexception, android-sdcard

I read the images from my sdcard and store the paths in an array inside an activity, and it works fine and this reading is inside a method. The second time, i call the same method from another activity but the cursor returns null........i can say the problem is with "this", but cant figure out where to change. Below the code of the method.

```
 public void LoadImagesFromSDCard()
{
    try
    {
        String[] projection = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};           

        ContentResolver cr = this.getContentResolver();

        cursor = cr.query(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,projection,null,null,null);
        imageCount = cursor.getCount();
        imagePath = new String[imageCount + 1];
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        int cursor_index = 0;
        do
        {
                int id = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
                imagePath[cursor_index++] = cursor.getString(id);

        }while(cursor.moveToPosition(cursor_index));

     ........
```

and i call it the second time from another activity like this

```
    Camera.PictureCallback mPictureCallback = new Camera.PictureCallback() {
    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] imageData, Camera c) {


        if (imageData != null) {

            Intent mIntent = new Intent();

            StoreByteImage(mContext, imageData, 50,"ImageName");
            mCamera.startPreview();
            setResult(FOTO_MODE, mIntent);
            CameraTaken = true;

            IS.LoadImagesFromSDCard();
            finish();


        }
    }
};
```

actually this is a camera activity for the information. Thanks in advance for the help :)

here is the logcat

```
E/CameraTest(19169): onCreate
E/CameraTest(19169): onResume
E/CameraTest(19169): surfaceCreated
D/CameraHardwareStub(   34): initHeapLocked: preview size=320x240
E/CameraTest(19169): surfaceChanged
D/CameraHardwareStub(   34): initHeapLocked: preview size=320x240
I/ActivityManager(   59): Displayed activity com.android.print/.CameraActivity: 1013   ms (total 1013 ms)
D/AudioSink(   34): bufferCount (4) is too small and increased to 12
I/global  (19169): Default buffer size used in BufferedOutputStream constructor. It would be better to be explicit if an 8k buffer is required.
E/Error reading file(19169): java.lang.NullPointerException
E/CameraTest(19169): surfaceDestroyed
E/CameraTest(19169): onStop
```

Comment: what is IS in IS.LoadImagesFromSDCard();.........

Comment: IS is the object of the activity which has the method LoadFrom...()....

Comment: you can make the function static..otherwise u may never access from outside !!

Comment: if i make it static, i cant create an intent inside picture callback

Answer (score 0):

Refer Source code here http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/107270/Recording-and-Playing-Video-on-Android

Answer (score 0):

Ok i have solved the issue, i guess, since what i did is working.
The point is my first activity is in background and i call the camera activity from the first, which makes the first activity to go background. So i had to add android:launchMode="singleTask" for the first activity in manifest file. Then i explicitly call the first activity which is running in background instead of **IS.LoadImagesFromSDCard();**. Doing so it invokes the onNewIntent() in the first activity instead of onCreate(). And inside the onNewIntent() i call my LoadFrom...() method.

```
    Camera.PictureCallback mPictureCallback = new Camera.PictureCallback() {
    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] imageData, Camera c) {


        if (imageData != null) {

            Intent mIntent = new Intent();
            Intent inent = new Intent();

            StoreByteImage(mContext, imageData, 50,"ImageName");
            mCamera.startPreview();
            setResult(FOTO_MODE, mIntent);
            CameraTaken = true;
            ImageSelectionIntent.setClassName("your package name", "your package name + class name");
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
```

and the my first activity has the below code

```
 protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
      super.onNewIntent(intent);
      setIntent(intent);        
      LoadImagesFromSDCard();
    }
        }
    }
};
```

referred the link below

[communicating between two activities while the one called the other still running in background](http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/communicating-between-running-activities)